# Limit in WHERE-Clause subquery

Tags: soql

I want to do a query like this:

```sql
SELECT Id, Name, Email 
FROM User 
WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT OwnerId 
    FROM Opportunity
    WHERE AccountId = '001610000085XsNAAU'
    ORDER BY LastActivityDate DESC NULLS LAST
    LIMIT 1
)
```

But I have an error:

> expecting a right parentheses, found 'ORDER'

Isn't it possible to use `ORDER` and `LIMIT` in subqueries?

Comment: May i know where you are writing this query?

Comment: @Subhash I am testing it in Workbench. [link](https://workbench.developerforce.com)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: No, you can't use `ORDER` and `LIMIT` in [semi-join subqueries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm?search_text=semi):

> `COUNT`, `FOR UPDATE`, `ORDER BY`, and `LIMIT` aren’t supported in semi-join subqueries.

The purpose of semi-join queries is to restrict the records returned not selecting related records, thus using `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` makes no sense in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write the query in 3 steps such as:

```
List<Opportunity> opps = [SELECT id,OwnerId FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = '001610000085XsNAAU' ORDER BY LastActivityDate DESC NULLS LAST Limit 1];

Set<Id> ids= new Set<id>();
for(Opportunity o :opps){
    ids.add(o.ownerId);
}

List<User> users = [SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM User WHERE Id IN : ids];
```